# Why does xliff in android displays format specifier in Edittext hint?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-resources, xliff, string.xml

I am working on localization if an app in android studio. While using xliff in the below code, I see the "%s" display in my screen.

```
<string name="name">Name <xliff:g id="get_name" example="Diana">%s</xliff:g></string>
```

I know that the %s is supposed to display any text that is input by the user.

Below is my activity.xml code:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/name_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/name"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"/>
```

In the output, I want the hint to be shown as **Name** but it shows as **Name %s**. is this a normal behavior? Is there anything that I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear, what you want to achieve by using `xliff` in `EditText`.

As far as I understand for your concrete task of localization I beleive you don't need to use `xliff` in your `string`.
If you're on Windows just create an additional folder in `...\AndroidStudioProjects\YourApp\app\src\main\res`

For example if you want to add spanish language create `values-es` folder and add there another `strings.xml`, where all text is in spanish, like:

`<string name="name">Nombre</string>`

When a user downloads your app from Google Play, his device will automatically switch language to the one, that is chosen in Android OS.